# What happens when answers become wrong?

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer, policy

What is the policy of dealing with answers that would become wrong after time? As an example, if I asked the question *Does java support the Elvis operator ?:* the correct answer today is **no**. The correct answer when Java7 becomes widely available will be **yes**.

What would be done in that case?

- Re-tag old java questions with java5 or java6?
- Keep them and hope people correct the answers?
- Something else?

Answer (score 10):

Edit the answer to say "As of version x, it is now supported. Previous to that, it was not." That's exactly why SO is wiki-like.

Comment: The only difficulty is in keeping the answers up to date.

Comment: @TXI I'm pretty sure for most topics (at least the most popular ones) we've got more than a few people who spend their Saturday nights making sure their pet topic is clean and up-to-date :)

Comment: @Rex M: Don't you *dare* judge me.