# What should we do when the situation changes for an old question that already has an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer

Consider this question as specific example: [iPad keyboard will not dismiss if modal ViewController presentation style is UIModalPresentationFormSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372333/ipad-keyboard-will-not-dismiss-if-navigation-controller-presentation-style-is-fo)

The answer that is currently accepted was indeed the correct answer when the question was asked. But with recent software updates (iOS 4.0 in particular), the answer has now changed. I don't like to switch my accepted answer because this would cause whoever originally answered to insta-lose 15 rep.

How should we deal with a situation like this?

What if an "old" question with a new answer could switch the accepted answer to that new answer, giving the new answer something like 5 rep, but leaving the 15 rep with the old answer (maybe marking it as "previous answer" or something)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, we don't need this. If the situation has *changed* since the question was originally asked, then the previously accepted answer **is no longer correct** and thus not the most useful answer to the question.

In that case, the appropriate thing to do would be to post a new, updated answer to the question and accept that one. This will "unaccept" the previously-accepted answer, but that's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Ignore the reputation changes that might or might not happen behind the scenes. That's merely an implementation detail. Focus on picking the *best* answer to the question, the one that is/was most useful to you and will be most useful to future Googlers who arrive in search of an answer to the same question.

(Of course, if you're only making relatively *minor* updates or additions to the currently-accepted answer because it is still mostly correct, then you should just edit it and leave it as the accepted answer.)

You definitely should not include the updated answer in the *question*, as you've done in the example. That's quite confusing. The system is explicitly designed to keep questions separate from answers. There's nothing wrong with updating your question with new information, but you shouldn't update questions with new *answers*. Always post those as answers.

Related reading:

- [Is it "bad" to unaccept an accepted answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98070/is-it-bad-to-unaccept-an-accepted-answer)
- [What is the etiquette for correcting old questions with incorrect answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5408/what-is-the-etiquette-for-correcting-old-questions-with-incorrect-answers)
- [Is it poor form to switch accepted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62252/is-it-poor-form-to-switch-accepted-answers)
- [What happens when answers become wrong?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21791/what-happens-when-answers-become-wrong)
- [What to do when the correct answer to a question changes over time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47962/what-to-do-when-the-correct-answer-to-a-question-changes-over-time)

Comment: You mean `This will ***not*** "unaccept" the previously-accepted answer`?

Comment: @Bobby: No, I don't think so. Double negatives have always been hard for me, but if you accept a new answer, the old answer will not be accepted any more.

Comment: Ops, I completely missed that you were talking about his *own* question. I should seriously stop drive-by-commenting. :/ My apologizes.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'll see about cleaning up that question and accept the other answer then.

Comment: Moderators can change the selected answer?

Answer (score 7):

Why not simply edit the question to include the context (iOS version) that was implied or obvious at the time? That leaves all the answers as still correct answers to that question. You can then add a comment to one of the answers that says "btw, this behaviour changed in [new version] so this answer only applies to [old version].

The alternative, where the question still assumes some current version or context, some of the answers are speaking to an old version without saying so (and have upvotes) and others have been updated to a new version - it's just a mess.