# How to get a new answer for an old question

Tags: discussion, questions, old-questions

Seems like this question should have already been asked on Meta, but I could not find it.

[What should we do when the situation changes for an old question that already has an accepted answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98897/what-should-we-do-when-the-situation-changes-for-an-old-question-that-already-ha) 
is similar, but my question more has to do with requesting an update on a question that is not mine, rather than what to do once it is updated.

My question is how to get an update on an old question. I found [Java Voice Biometric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724454/java-voice-biometric) and the question itself (and the updated comment) is outdated and now useless. I would like to ask the question again however I know it will be tagged as `duplicate`.

How should I go about getting a completely new set of answers for a question like this?

Comment: [Bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on existing question with good reason might help you.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar while that seems like the way to go currently, it does not make sense to me that I cannot troll through SO and find old answers that need updating and "vote for an update" or similar. Given my low standing the question is not extremely important to me, however giving it some modern attention would help users...

Comment: @HaydenKai then answer it yourself, or edit the question with new relevant information as to why the current answers are outdated... or leave it.

Comment: @Cai ah! just realized that edits bump up the question to get attention. Yes updating it with some of my current efforts makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 8):

Bounty:

> [image]

There is even a whole reason for this:

> [image]

Comment: Can you add a comment and your opinion on the strategy of: editing an old question with some new info (your current attempts), therefore bringing new attention to it, and if that doesnt work go for the bounty?

Answer (score 3):

You can post a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on this question; there is a [bounty reason](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/) for **exactly this purpose**.

> #### Current answers are outdated
>
> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.

Comment: Makes sense, but new users coming on may find a lot of useless answers on some subject because they are outdated, and they can't spend the reputation to get it updated. It would make more sense to request that something is deleted and then re-ask the question because in my case, it would have been better if the question never existed (I would have just asked it and gotten a good answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could actually just ask the question again. If a question has old outdated answers, you could explain that when and if they flag your question as a duplicate.

You could also try commenting on the question and asking for an update.

Comment: This is what I am probably going to attempt, given the other answers to this question. The answers to my SO question are useless, and there is no point in spending reputation to just ask a valid question.

Comment: That's not the way to do it, unless *the question* has also changed. Answers being outdated does not make the question itself any less of a duplicate.

Comment: @Cai I agree, now that I see a way to make the old post visible again by editing